# Как выключить форматирование в теге script в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Как выключить форматирование в теге script в phpstorm?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Единственный способ выключить форматирование для куска кода - использовать [formatter markers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/settings-code-style.html#1fcce0d7):

```
<!--@formatter:off-->
  <script type=text/javascript>
    //your code here
  </script>
<!--@formatter:on-->
```

**Settings | Editor | Code Style, Formatter Control**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно вообще отключить и автоформатирование и форматирование при вставке, либо по отдельности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]